# Sqaure brackets & asterisk sign as WildCards chars in Redis keys or scan with match

Tags: regex, redis, nosql

We query redis using SCAN command along with MATCH, in following manner:

```
scan 0 MATCH "S*"
```

this will find anything starting with `S`

then there is a square brackets syntax is also supported(`[]`) which `OR`

```
scan 0 MATCH "[ef]*"
```

this will find anything that's starting with `e` OR `f`

Now, 
I am looking to combination of both.

1. match anything that start with `e` OR `f`
2. AND match anything that has `S` after `e` OR `f`

I came up with following:

```
scan 0 MATCH "[ef]S*"
```

But this just keep running without any results. is is the above correct? let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should work as is - verified locally:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FLUSHALL
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MSET a "" e "" f "" eSz "" fSx "" efg "" fgi "" SSX ""
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 0 MATCH "[ef]S*"
1) "0"
2) 1) "eSz"
   2) "fSx"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: so it seems I was right, its just my data set is huge. 38Million keys, so its taking time.